# Creating a simple Dock Cell that Fades In when Cursor Hover Over It

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, gui-construction, docked-cell

I like to create dock cells, that enhance the look of my notebooks.  Do you know of a simple way to get the functionality in iBooks shown below in the video.  I want the dock cell in Mathematica to "fade" into view when my cursor hover over it and "fade" out when it's not hovering over it.

[image]

Edit 1:  Thank you Karsten.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Below is a gif implementing a version of your code.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Edit: Fading overlay window

In order to get a top dock element with real transparency, one can create a window that overlays the current notebook window and adjusts its position together with it.

```
With[{nb = EvaluationNotebook[]},
  DynamicModule[{wm, ws},
   CreateWindow[
    PaletteNotebook[
     {DynamicWrapper[TextCell["Click OK to close", Orange], 
       ws = {CurrentValue[nb, WindowSize][[1]] - 15, 100}; 
       wm = AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, WindowMargins] + {{7, 0}, {70, 50}}, 
       Initialization :> (wm = 
          AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, WindowMargins] + {{7, 0}, {70, 50}}; 
         ws = {CurrentValue[nb, WindowSize][[1]] - 15, 100})],
      DefaultButton[]}
     , WindowMargins -> Dynamic[Setting@wm], WindowSize -> Dynamic[Setting@ws]
     , TextAlignment -> Center]
    , Background -> Blue
    , WindowOpacity -> 
     Dynamic[1/
       100 (150 - 
         Replace[MousePosition["WindowAbsolute", {0, 1}], None -> {0, 150}][[2]])]
    , WindowFloating -> True, WindowElements -> {}, WindowFrame -> "Frameless"
    , WindowFrameElements -> {}]
   ]];
```

[image: TopDock]

---

One can use [`PaneSelector`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PaneSelector.html) to create a fading effect.

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells] =
 Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@PaneSelector[{
      False -> 
       Panel["", ImageSize -> {Full, Automatic}, Appearance -> "Frameless"],
      True -> Panel["Hi", ImageSize -> {Full, Automatic}, Alignment -> Center]
      },
     Dynamic@CurrentValue["MouseOver"]
     , ImageSize -> All
     , ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> None
     , TransitionEffect -> "Fade", TransitionDirection -> Bottom, TransitionDuration -> 0.75
     ]
  , CellFrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

[image: DC1]

The size of the `DockedCells` can be reduces, when the mouse isn't hovering over it:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells] =
 Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@PaneSelector[{
      False -> Panel["", ImageSize -> {Full, 0}, Appearance -> "Frameless"],
      True -> Panel["Hi", ImageSize -> {Full, 100}, Alignment -> Center]
      },
     Dynamic@CurrentValue["MouseOver"]
     , ImageSize -> Automatic
     , ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> None
     , TransitionEffect -> "Fade", TransitionDirection -> Bottom, TransitionDuration -> 0.75
     ]]
```

[image: DC2]

Comment: I implemented your code.  It works great.  See new gif in original post.  I do get some strange behavior with the images fading in and out from right to left or sometimes jumping without fading.  The TransitionDirection option doesn't seem to help. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain The `TransitionDirection` has no effect, when the `TransitionEffect` is `"Fade"`. The fading effect is "cleaner", when using `False -> Invisible@Panel[...]` with `Panel[...]` being the same one as for `True`.

Comment: That worked!  Nice and clean transition now.  +1000000.  TY

Comment: The `PaneSelector` option setting `ContentPadding -> False` can be used to prevent a vertical movement during the transitions.

Comment: @Karsten7. I added what it looks like on my laptop, some weirdness going on...

Comment: @Karsten7. yes I just tried adding that, and the flickering is still there

Comment: @M.R. I'm not sure if you mean the change in size with flickering, but that looks like the `ImageSize -> All` option isn't working correctly on macOS. Should be independent of `DockedCells`. If you can reproduce the incorrect behavior for `PaneSelector` outside `DockedCells`, then that should be a separate question.

Comment: @M.R. Maybe removing the `Appearance -> "Frameless"` options fixes the behavior. One can use `Background -> Transparent` instead.

Comment: @Karsten7. I added a solution similar to Kuba's that works for sierra... did you every get the transparency to work so you can scroll under it?

Comment: i.e. when not active the docked cell isn't just white space?

Comment: @M.R. When using a transparent cell for `DockedCells` the Toolbar with `CurrentValue["ToolbarBackground"]` as its background is still overlaying the content of the notebook. Please see my edit for an alternative solution with real transparency.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my take (works smooth for macOS sierra).

```
content = Row[Button /@ {"a", "b", "c"}, " "];

CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells] = 
 Cell[BoxData @ ToBoxes @ Mouseover[
     ExpressionCell[Pane[Invisible@Button@""], "Text"], 
     ExpressionCell[Pane[content, ImageSize -> Full, Alignment -> Center], "Text"], ImageSize -> Full, TransitionEffect -> "Fade"], 
  Background -> Transparent, CellFrame -> 0]
```

[image]

But the dock isn't transparent! Don't know if that's possible...

Comment: You are good at this. :)

Answer (score 5):

Smooth fade effect probably won't be simple but here is a start:

```
CurrentValue[ EvaluationNotebook[],  DockedCells] = {
   Cell[ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ Mouseover[
      1,
      Grid@RandomReal[1, {3, 3} ],
      ImageSize -> {Full, Full}, 
      Alignment -> Center], 
    "DockedCell"]
}
```

Comment: is the transparency for seeing the content scrolling under the docked bar possible?

Comment: @M.R. so Karsten answered that already :) I forgot about that option :)

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I did try the suggestion about using Background -> Transparent, this doesn't work

Comment: @M.R. ah, I see. Maybe there is a way but I'm not aware of it :/