# Long output fade-out effect?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

Is there a method to truncate & fade out output expressions programmatically, essentially the same effect as seen (arrow) in this screenshot from 11.3 presentation:

[image]

I asked tech support but was told that was done by processing bitmaps, which is not scalable for my application. 11.3 features a new `Iconize` function which shortens input expression, so I'm looking for "FadeOut".

A related Q is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128025/creating-a-simple-dock-cell-that-fades-in-when-cursor-hover-over-it), but seems overkill.

Comment: If image processing solution won't work for you, what about `Shallow`?

Comment: @Kuba, Shallow doesn't work well (or at all) with `Dataset` and even nested `Associations`. Also it doesn't look as good or is as effective as the fade in terms of pre-attentive visualization (Colin Ware): the fade is immediately obvious, whereas the users have to interpret the` <<...>>` output.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you if you rule out image processing.

Comment: @Kuba, the application is for a book project and is used throughout. Images would be too low-res.

Comment: What about: `expr = Dataset@RandomReal[1, {20, 10}];

size = {300, 300};
Overlay[{
  Pane[expr, size],
  Image[
   SetAlphaChannel[
      ColorNegate@#, 
      ColorNegate@
       AlphaChannel@
        ImageEffect[#, {"FadedFrame", Scaled[1/5], {Bottom, Right}}]
      ] &@Image@ConstantArray[0, size]
   ]
  
  }]`

Comment: @Kuba, that looks great. In testing a `Dataset` with keys etc, sometimes looks good but would have to adjust the `size` param. Rectangular, eg {300,400} isn't properly registered and parts show through after the fade.